# Possible to install just Bootstrap CSS with Bower?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower, angular-ui-bootstrap

Starting a new Angular project via Yeoman asks if you want to include Twitter Bootstrap (I'm using Sass flavor). Doing so includes both the styles and scripts. However, I want to use [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead of Bootstrap's scripts (which depend on jQuery).

So, is it possible to install only Bootstrap's styles (preferably in Sass) with Bower? Or do I just need to download and include the Bootstrap styles manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just add `exclude` option in grunt bowerInstall task, and bowerInstall task will not inject the excluded file in the html file

```
bowerInstall: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'],
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
  }
},
```

Comment: You can also probably exclude jQuery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'

Answer (score 17):

I know one CSS-only Bootstrap packages in Bower: `bootstrap-css-only`; However it comes with precompiled CSS but not SASS.

Comment: https://github.com/jozefizso/bower-bootstrap-css also contains built files, and goes all the way back to 2.3.0, in case anyone needs that, in the age of bower being deprecated!

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289270/265570), you could add this to `.bowerrc` to delete the Bootstrap JS files:

`{
  "directory": "bower_components",
  "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "rm -rf bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts"
    }
}`

Answer (score 3):

if you don't have a bowerInstall task in your gruntfile as mentioned in the accepted answer, this also works in the wiredep task.

```
 wiredep: {
  app: {
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
    exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'],
    ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

You can execute:

```
bower install bootstrap-css-only
```