# grunt-bower-install: exclude certain components

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower, grunt-usemin

I just created a new webapp using the angular-fullstack yeoman generator.

I noticed that grunt-bower-install is generating the JS bower components in my index.html files between the `<!-- bower:js -->` tags.

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

How do I exclude certain bootstrap components?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The plugin grunt-bower-install (aka grunt-wiredep) supports an 'exclude' parameter to list the components that you do now want to be automatically injected.

For example, if you didn't want dropdown included just list that component with full pathname:

```
'bower-install': {
      app: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/views/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/',
        exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js']
      }
    },
```

And then run again grunt bower-install.

For further options see the underline library wiredep: https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep

Comment: This helped me, but I was only able to exclude the entire component by using the component name(exclude: ['respond']).  Using the full js file path did not work.

Comment: @Lee It seems I experience the same behavior. I can not exclude the bootstrap.js file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466137/bower-exclude-component-does-not-work Should it be only possible to exclude a WHOLE component? and not files of it?

Comment: Does not work, i have tried every possible file pattern.