# Bower override dependency

Tags: underscore.js, bower, lodash, jointjs

I have an application, written in Backbone with Marionette and some other dependencies, managed through **bower** :

```
{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "main": "public/javascripts/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "console-polyfill": "~0.1.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "normalize-css": "~2.1.2",
    "marionette": "~1.7.4",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
    "backbone-pageable": "~1.4.5",
    "moment": "~2.5.1",
    "swag": "~0.6.1",
    "jquery-form": "~3.46.0",
    "jquery-file-upload": "~9.5.7",
    "underscore.string": "~2.3.3",
    "bootstrap-switch": "~3.0.1",
    "joint": "~0.9.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "backbone": {
      "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "*",
        "jquery": "*"
      },
      "main": "backbone.js"
    },
    "backbone.wreqr": {
      "dependencies": {
        "backbone": "*"
      },
      "main": "lib/amd/backbone.wreqr.js"
    },
    "backbone-pageable": {
      "dependencies": {
        "backbone": "*"
      },
      "main": "lib/backbone-pageable.js"
    },
    "jquery-file-upload": {
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "*"
      },
      "main": [
        "js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js",
        "js/jquery.iframe-transport.js",
        "js/jquery.fileupload.js"
      ]
    },
    "underscore.string": {
      "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "*"
      },
      "main": "lib/underscore.string.js"
    },
    "joint": {
      "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "*"
      },
      "main": "dist/joint.clean.js"
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1"
  }
}
```

I want to add **Joint.js**(http://www.jointjs.com/), which depends on **lodash** (a replacement for **underscore**), but I can't figure out how to replace this in my configuration, since Marionette, Backbone, and some other libraries depend on underscore directly. So on the load underscore overrides lodash, and application can't start correctly.

Comment: Why don't you let `lodash` overwrite `underscore`? Their API should be compatible.

Comment: This is what I expected, would happen, but underscore overrode lodash at the end.

Comment: I've changed the order, and put lodash as the latest dependency, and it worked. Thanks for a hint:) I'll leave this hopping there is a cleaner way to do it, otherwise I'm loading both libraries on the client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed the order, and put lodash as the latest dependency, and it worked.

Also as a solution there is an option to have a bower hook, like it states in following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289270/575338

> We had a similar situation where we had Backbone depend on Underscore
>   in its `bower.json`, but we're using Lo-Dash in its stead, so Bower
>   was unnecessarily pulling down Underscore for each install. We have
>   automated checks for 3rd party license compliance, so we didn't want
>   anything we don't actually use.
>
> I realize this isn't exactly what they're meant for, but Bower's
>   [install-hooks](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/HOOKS.md)
>   can be used to clean unneeded deps post-install (at least until Bower
>   gets the sort of "no thanks" resolution you hinted at). In your
>   `.bowerrc`:
>
> ```
> {
>     "directory": "app/bower_components",
>     "scripts": {
>         "postinstall": "rm -rf app/bower_components/underscore"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It's a bit of a hack, but works.

Comment: Note that from version 1.4. of Bower you should be able to add a ignoreDependencies array to your bower.json