# how do angularJS user handle - using bootstrap css/fonts but exclude the jquery controls - scenario

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, bower

I am using angularjs and angularjs ui bootstrap module.

I am also using the bower package bootstrap-css-only because I do not need the jquery bootstrap plugins. All I want is the boostrap-css-only.

But I have other bower packages which have dependencies to bootstrap package and whenever I update those packages having dependencies to bootstrap package they install the latest bootstrap package including the jquery stuff which I do not need.

That means ALL bootstrap stuff + the bootstrap css only is loaded into my browser!!!

How can I prevent this scenario? I can not remove the entry 'bootstrap' from other bower packages dependecies configuration like textAngular:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.2.x",
    "bootstrap": "^3.0.x",
    "font-awesome": "^4.0.x",
    "rangy": "^1.2.0"
  },
```

textAngular does not depend on bootstrap-css-only. Oh yes I could change the above bootstrap with bootstrap-css-only but at the next textAngular update its gone... and I forget that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [permanently ignore a dependency with bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938808/permanently-ignore-a-dependency-with-bower)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [permanently ignore a dependency with bower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20938808/1413689), but the accepted answer is probably not what you are looking for, I actually think this answer is more what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791606/1413689

FYI: For textAngular's case the latest release has changed to bootstrap-css-only
https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/v1.3.4/changelog.md
https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/issues/527