# Installing bootstrap-sass and bootswatch with Bower

Tags: installation, bower, bootstrap-sass

`bower i --save bootstrap-sass bootswatch` installs bootstrap also.
So When I `wiredep`, `index.html` have two bootstrap.js.
like...

```
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
```

How can I Install bootstrap-sass only?

---

I'm using bower 1.7.9

Answer (score 0):

[permanently ignore a dependency with bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938808/permanently-ignore-a-dependency-with-bower/27791606#27791606)

I have found answer there. I added .bowerrc and

```
{
  "ignoredDependencies": [
    "bootstrap",
    "bootstrap-sass-official"
  ]
}
```

then it skipped `bootstrap` when installing `bootswatch`.

Adding `override` in .bower.json didn't work.